# Do homemade pregnancy tests with sugar work?

Tags: biology, alternative-medicine

There are a lot of claims on the internet (like [this one](http://www.onlymyhealth.com/homemade-pregnancy-test-with-sugar-1400834810)) that it is possible to test for pregnancy by just putting sugar in a glass and urinating on it. The hormones in the urine supposedly cause the sugar to clump. There are endless variations on it, using baking powder, toothpaste, vinegar, bleach or other household products.

*Is there any scientific evidence that such tests work, or do not work?*

If they do work, how well do they work, and why are they not adopted by mainstream pharma, and advocated by physicians?

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes things can surprise you. Can you find more instances of this claim (preferably specifically referencing sugar) to establish notability?

Comment: Definitely notable, I heard about this on the radio couple of weeks ago.

Comment: *Water* causes sugar to clump (or to dissolve, if there's enough of it).  I'd be amazed if this actually works.

Comment: @Mark, I think the idea is that adding enough urine will eventually dissolve the sugar (in the case of a non-pregnant woman), but the urine of a pregnant woman supposedly always causes the sugar to clump, no matter how much urine is added.

Comment: YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9lsPsiODkk and other text links: [1](http://www.checkpregnancy.com/best-6-homemade-pregnancy-tests/) [2](http://www.momjunction.com/articles/homemade-pregnancy-test_00373199/#gref) [3](http://www.menmomhealth.com/homemade-pregnancy-test-with-sugar-at-home-negative-result/)

Comment: @Erica, that's exactly what I mean by "claims on the internet". None of them is from a peer-reviewed journal.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstand -- I was supplying additional instances of the claim (to establish notability), DEFINITELY NOT trying to say "here's some proof" :)

Comment: <sarcasm>Not only that; sugar is also an effective vaginal contraceptive. Try it! (Disclaimer, like on the page you link to: Regardless of sugar's effectiveness as a contraceptive, you should always also use the one your doctor prescribed.) </sarcasm>

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Eventually it's very effective. Put some sugar up there and watch the fungi grow. Eventually you'll be in so much pain that you can't have sex anymore. Perfect contraception.</sarcasm>

Comment: Instead of wasting some good sugar why not buy a regular pregnancy test?